# where did my white mage called meremirmu go in the Heir to the throne

Tags: battle-for-wesnoth

I recently started playing battle or wesnoth and i completed the mission with meremirmu within the time limit (last turn) so that the white mage will join me. Miremirmu even tells me that he will join my team and I was exited to see him in the next mission. Yet when the mission starts he is nowhere to be seen. Is this how its supposed to be? does the white mage join you later on in game. It just doesnt seem right. Am i experiencing some sort of bug.

The reason why im asking is because I do not want to keep playing next missions just to realize i need to redo the old mission to get my white mage to come with me.

Does anybody remember if the mage goes to the next mission or not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following the mission in which you gain his allegiance he can be deployed via `alt-r` unit like your other veterans.

Comment: they are a little bit tricky with this because they tell you he is coming with you but then you dont see him next mission. So i thought he is a goner. as soon as i see him i will mark ur answer. :) Thank you for quick response.

Comment: actually he can be bought right away on the next mission

Comment: Answer amended.